# Jenkins - How to only archive latest version

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, archive, bukkit

I just want to archive the latest jar, while keeping version on the jar.

In my pom I have the

```
<finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
```

Which dynamically changes version. But when I have Jenkins archive target/**.jar, it archives every old build. Is there a way to only archive the latest version? I tried to see if I could use the POM's maven variables, but it didn't look like I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 : cleaning

You may just the following command

> mvn clean package

instead of

> mvn package

It will remove all artifacts and previous compiled classes.
So, Jenkins won't upload all jars in you repo.

### Solution 2 : deploy

You could also rune the following command, that only require maven configuration (Jenkins independant)

> mvn clean deploy

This will indeed push your maven artifacts into your local repo (like install) and then into you main / corporate repo.
It require more configuration (pom.xml > repositories, distribution management, settings.xml  > accounts / credentials.

Take a lool here :

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/
- http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html#lifecycle-sect-deploy-phase

**This is the right way to do what you want to achieve.**